# Why doesn't interface protect me in this case?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IA {
    readonly a: string;
    f(x: string): void;
}

class X implements IA {
    a;
    f(x) {
        this.a = 1;
    }
}

let x = new X().a;
```

Surprisingly, this code compiles.

- It infers the type of `X.a` as `any`, why is that?
- `readonly` doesn't seem to protect me from modifying a. Am I using it wrong?

#### Update

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much down to any non-typed variable implicitly being `any`. You can disable that in the compiler options:

```
  "noImplicitAny": true
```

at which point you will have to define a type that can be assigned to the base-interface type.

[image]

as for the read-only. its working as intended:

[image]

you have to understand there are some differences between typescript and other OO languages like C#. Namely that the assignment of one typed variable to another is all about whether the right-side type intersects with the left-side type. i.e.

```
let x: X = { a: "hello", f: (x) => { } };
```

is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

It infers `X.a` as any because you haven't specified the type.
When your class implements an interface it must then specify all of what the interface defined, if you won't include the member `a`:

```
class X implements IA {
    f(x) {
        this.a = 3;
    }
}
```

You'll get:

> Class 'X' incorrectly implements interface 'IA'.
>   Property 'a' is missing in type 'X'

And

> Property 'a' does not exist on type 'X'

You don't get any errors for not including the type for `a`, and that's because it's automatically `any` and that satisfies the compiler.
You can tell the compiler to check for this by using `noImplicitAny` in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied ‘any’ type

The `readonly` part is not enforced because it's only `readonly` in the `IA` interface but not for the class:

```
class X implements IA {
    a;
    f(x) {
        (this as IA).a = ""; // Error: Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property
    }
}
```

And:

```
class X implements IA {
    readonly a;
    f(x) {
        this.a = ""; // Error: Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your class should also specify the `readonly` keyword and the type:

```
class X implements IA {
    readonly a: string;
```